# Photos needed for product attributes?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, color-swatches

I have some shirts that the client can choose the size, color and also add a custom text and choose the color of the text. My problem is that I'm not sure if I have a photo of each shirt color without text, in addition to a photo for each color with each text in the different colors (the photo of the shirt with text would be an example text since the you can customize it)

Is there any way to do this? or should I have a picture for each shirt color and text color?